# Java version does not apply on Mac

Tags: java, zsh, java-11, javac

I am trying to set my machines javac version to 11 from 18.0.2 and I'm doing the following steps

1. open ~/.zshenv
2. export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v11)
3. source ~/.zshenv

When I check the version, I still get it as 18.0.2. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.
Could someone please help me with this? Been stuck on this forever.

Comment: You might also want to ask this on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Check your PATH variable or try where is javac. Sounds like the path is pointing to the v18 executable.

Comment: @kiwiron `echo $PATH` returns this `/Users/xxx/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/xxx/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/xxx/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/xxx/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: By the way, a suggestion: https://sdkman.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works like a charme for me is using jenv: https://www.jenv.be/

With jenv you can also switch between different Java versions.

Before using jenv, I relied on the Maven toolchains plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-toolchains-plugin/

Thus, I actually never really worried about `JAVA_HOME` on MacOS. Maybe one of these options also is an alternative for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to change the version using jenv, however when I run the command `javac --version` I get `18.0.2`

Comment: Nvm I just had to refresh the terminal. Thank you sir, spent countless hours on this!

Answer (score 0):

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`
```

Comment: still spits the old version when I do `echo $JAVA_HOME`
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this typo is only in your question here, but you need to put a space between "-v" and "11":

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).